# Interoperability Macromedia Freehand and Esri ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, interoperability

I will receive a Adobe Macromedia FreeHand file, which contains multiple vector data that I have to export, so that they can be used in ArcGIS.

Does anyone know in which format FreeHand stores vectors by default and to which formats - that are interoperable with ArcGIS - they can be exported?

A list of ArcGIS interoperable foramts can be found here: http://www.esri.com/library/fliers/pdfs/data-interop-formats.pdf

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Macromedia Freehand will export to DWG/DXF CAD file formats.  If you have access to Freehand you could open and export the file directly.  ArcGIS Desktop will open DWG/DXF files.

Alternatively (and since it's about 10-15 years since Freehand was last released!), Adobe Illustrator (and possibly other applications in Adobe's software suite) will open Freehand files and will also output to DWG/DXF files.

Disclaimer: It has been a long time since I've used any of this software, so I'm not entirely sure if it's still possible with current releases!